# Retrieving data from commonsware endlessAdapter

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, commonsware-cwac

Originally, I have my own `Adapter extended the BaseAdapter` and it works fine. Then, I tried to adopt the commonsware EndlessAdapter by the following code:

```
public class MyEndlessAdapter extends EndlessAdapter {
private RotateAnimation rotate = null;
private View pendingView = null;
private List<Map<String, Object>> mData = null;
private String link, type;
String[] videoInfo= new String[90];
private Bitmap[] thumbnail = new Bitmap[10];
Context context;

public MyEndlessAdapter(Context ctxt, List<Map<String, Object>> data) {
    super(new MyEndlessAdapter(ctxt, data));
    new MyAdapter(ctxt, data);
    context = ctxt;
    rotate = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotate.setDuration(600);
    rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
    rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
}

public List<Map<String, Object>> get() {
    MyAdapter a2 = (MyAdapter) getWrappedAdapter();
    return a2.get();
}

@Override
protected View getPendingView(ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.row, null);

    pendingView = row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    pendingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    pendingView = row.findViewById(R.id.throbber);
    pendingView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    startProgressAnimation();

    return (row);
}

public void getInfromation(String type, String link) {
    this.link = link;
    this.type = type;
}

@Override
protected boolean cacheInBackground() {
    SearchYoutube mySearchYoutube = new SearchYoutube();
    String jsonString = mySearchYoutube.YoutubeResult(link);
    Log.i("in AsycTask", "link=  " + link);
    Log.i("in AsycTask", "jsonString=  " + jsonString);
    videoInfo = mySearchYoutube.YoutubeJSONToString(jsonString);
    int arrayLength = mySearchYoutube.GetCounter();
    Log.i("in AsycTask", "arrayLength=  " + arrayLength);
    try {
        for (int j = 4, i = 0; j < arrayLength; j = j + 9, i++) {
            Log.i("Check bitmap", "before, j = " + j + "  ,i = " + i);
            Log.i("Check bitmap", "after" + videoInfo[j]);
            try {
                thumbnail[i] = BitmapFactory
                        .decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(videoInfo[j])
                                .getContent());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                thumbnail[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        context.getResources(), R.drawable.video_default);
            }
        }
        mData = getData(mData);
        return (getWrappedAdapter().getCount() < 200);
    } catch (Exception anyError) {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
protected void appendCachedData() {
    if (getWrappedAdapter().getCount() < 200) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        MyAdapter a = (MyAdapter) getWrappedAdapter();
        for (int i = 0; i < mData.size(); i++) {
            a.add(mData.get(i));
        }
    }
}

public void startProgressAnimation() {
    if (pendingView != null) {
        pendingView.startAnimation(rotate);
    }
}

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<Map<String, Object>> mData;

    public final class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView thumbnail_view;
        public TextView title_view;
        public TextView date_view;
        public TextView duration_view;
        // public Button save_btn;

    }

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Map<String, Object>> data) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mData = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        /**
         * Original holder
         * 
         * 
         * */
        // ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.vlist, null);
            holder.thumbnail_view = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_view);
            holder.title_view = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.title_view);
            holder.date_view = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.date_view);
            holder.duration_view = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.duration_view);
            // holder.save_btn =
            // (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Log.i("position< mData.size()", "count");
        holder.thumbnail_view.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) mData.get(position)
                .get("thumbnail"));
        holder.title_view
                .setText((String) mData.get(position).get("title"));
        holder.date_view.setText((String) mData.get(position).get(
                "uploaded"));
        holder.duration_view.setText((String) mData.get(position).get(
                "duration"));
        // holder.save_btn.setOnClickListener(new
        // myButtonListener(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    public void add(Map<String, Object> map) {

        mData.add(map);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public List<Map<String, Object>> get() {
        return mData;
    }

    class myButtonListener implements OnClickListener {
        private int position;

        myButtonListener(int pos) {
            position = pos;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int vid = v.getId();
            Log.i("onClick, button on list", "position is : " + position
                    + "  And vid : " + vid);

        }
    }

}

private List<Map<String, Object>> getData(List<Map<String, Object>> mList) {

    List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    if (mList != null||mList == null) {
        list = mList;
    }
    Log.v("In videoInfo List", "length");
    Map<String, Object> map;
    int arrayLength = videoInfo.length;

    for (int j = 0, i = 0; j < arrayLength; j++, i++) {
        map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Date d2 = new Date();
        videoInfo[j] = videoInfo[j].replaceAll("Z", "+0800");
        SimpleDateFormat dateformat1 = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
        Date youtubeDate = new Date();
        try {
            youtubeDate = dateformat1.parse(videoInfo[j]);
            Log.v("In videoInfo List", "youtubeDate: " + youtubeDate);
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        String time = "";
        String ago = " ago";
        int year, month, day, year2, month2, day2 = 0;
        int hour, minute, seccond, hour2, minute2, seccond2 = 0;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(youtubeDate);
        calendar2.setTime(d2);

        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        ;
        year2 = calendar2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        month2 = calendar2.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        day2 = calendar2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        hour2 = calendar2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        minute2 = calendar2.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        if (year2 - year > 0) {
            time = (year2 - year) + " years ago | ";
            map.put("uploaded", time);
        } else if (month - month > 0) {
            time = (month2 - month) + " months ago | ";
            map.put("uploaded", time);
        } else if (day2 - day > 0) {
            time = (day2 - day) + " days ago | ";
            map.put("uploaded", time);
        } else if (hour2 - hour > 0) {
            time = (hour2 - hour) + " hours ago | ";
            map.put("uploaded", time);
        } else if (minute2 - minute > 0) {
            time = (minute2 - minute) + " minutes ago | ";
            map.put("uploaded", time);
        }

        else {
            map.put("uploaded", "a few seconds ago | ");
        }

        // map.put("uploaded", videoInfo[j]);
        j++;
        map.put("category", videoInfo[j]);
        j++;
        map.put("title", videoInfo[j]);
        j++;
        map.put("description", videoInfo[j]);
        j++;
        map.put("thumbnail", thumbnail[i]);
        map.put("thumbnail_link", videoInfo[j]);
        j++;
        map.put("share_link", videoInfo[j]);
        Log.v("In videoInfo List", "share_link: " + videoInfo[j]);
        j++;
        map.put("youtube_link", videoInfo[j]);
        j++;
        map.put("rtsp", videoInfo[j]);
        Log.v("In videoInfo List", "rtsp: " + videoInfo[j]);
        j++;

        float a = Float.parseFloat(videoInfo[j]);
        int b = (int) a;
        int sec = b % 60;
        int min = b / 60;
        String duration;
        if (sec < 10) {
            duration = min + " : 0" + sec;
        } else {
            duration = min + " : " + sec;
        }
        // videoInfo[j] = duration;
        map.put("duration", duration);
        Log.v("In videoInfo List", "duration: " + duration);
        list.add(map);

    }

    Log.v("In videoInfo List", "list: " + list.size());

    return list;
}
}
```

And now I would like to retrieve the data from mData when a specific item is clicked in the main Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do it the same was as you did before. The `EndlessAdapter` does not change the `position` values given to you in methods like `onListItemClick()` of a `ListFragment`.

Comment: Thanks. Could I ask one more question? Where should I put the getWrappedAdapter() in the fragment example?

Comment: @crystalWing: Um, wherever you want, I suppose.